# Error "No worker is available to serve request: model" when calling SageMaker endpoint during increaesd load

Tags: flask, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, autoscaling

I have a custom container that takes a request, does some feature extraction and then passes on the enhanced request to a classifier endpoint. During feature extraction another endpoint is being called for generating text embeddings. I am using the [HuggingFace estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/huggingface/sagemaker.huggingface.html) for my embedding model.

It has been working fine, but there was an increase in requests and looks like the embedding endpoint timed out somehow.

I am looking at adding [automatic scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/load-test-and-optimize-an-amazon-sagemaker-endpoint-using-automatic-scaling/) to the endpoint, but I want to make sure I understand what is happening and that it properly addresses the issue. Unfortunately searching for this error message does not pull up much. The instance metrics is not showing the endpoint to be overloaded - cpu utilization was max ~30%. Would auto scaling address the no worker issue or is this something different? I was receiving a few hundred requests per minute at the time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/program/predictor.py", line 56, in transformation
    result = preprocessor.transform(data)
  File "/opt/program/preprocessor.py", line 189, in transform
    response = embed_predictor.predict(data=json.dumps(payload))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py", line 136, in predict
    response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)


botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (503) from primary with message "{
  "code": 503,
  "type": "ServiceUnavailableException",
  "message": "No worker is available to serve request: model"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest confirming `MemoryUtilization` is not being overwhelmed and there is no specifc error in CloudWatch Logs as well.

If `MemoryUtilization` is overwhelmed, you can test configuring Auto Scaling in order to distribute the load of request to multiple instances. That being said, while I am not sure of the details of your custom container, I also recommend confirming the container itself can handle multiple concurrent requests (i.e have multiple workers available to serve requests).